# How to properly use VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED?

Tags: vulkan

What I'm trying to achieve is load an image file into memory and copy its contents into a new `VkImage`. There's a lot of steps involved, but this question only seeks some clarification regarding the possibilities of using `_PREINITIALIZED` as the initial image layout.

---

According to the spec, I can use preinitialized image layout to remove the need for an initial layout transition:

> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED specifies that an image’s memory is in a defined layout and can be populated by data, but that it has not yet been initialized by the driver. Image memory cannot be transitioned into this layout. This layout can be used as the initialLayout member of VkImageCreateInfo. This layout is intended to be used as the initial layout for an image whose contents are written by the host, and hence the data can be written to memory immediately, without first executing a layout transition. Currently, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED is only useful with linear images because there is not a standard layout defined for VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL images.

This is my program flow:

```cpp
unsigned char* imgData = ... // image loaded from disk
VkBuffer stagingBuffer = ... // host-visible memory!

VkImageCreateInfo imageInfo{};
imageInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
imageInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR;
imageInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED; // <-- This is what I want!
VkImage img = // image created

vmaMapMemory(...); // on the staging buffer
memcpy(...); // using the mapped pointer and the loaded image data
vmaUnmap(...); // remove the mapping

VkCommandBuffer cmdBuf = ... // single-use transfer
vkBeginCommandBuffer(...);

VkBufferImageCopy copyRegion{}; // filled out appropriately
vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(cmdBuf, stagingBuffer, img, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED, 1, &copyRegion);

VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier{};
barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
barrier.image = img;
barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
// NOTE: I have also tried using VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL
barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED;
barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
    cmdBuf, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
    0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &barrier);

vkEndCommandBuffer(cmdBuf);
vkQueueSubmit(...); // do the stuff
```

---

I get a validation error which confuses me:

> Validation Error: [ VUID-vkCmdCopyBufferToImage-dstImageLayout-00181 ] Object 0: handle = 0x561d95599b70, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0x98877a9a | vkCmdCopyBufferToImage: Layout for VkImage 0x1c000000001c[] is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED but can only be VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL. The Vulkan spec states: dstImageLayout must be VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdCopyBufferToImage-dstImageLayout-00181)

I thought the whole point of having the possibility to specify `_PREINITIALIZED`was to explicitly NOT do an initial layout transition. But apparently, the image must be `_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL` - otherwise I can't write to it.

- It this setup at all possible?
- Should I use a staging image instead of a staging buffer
- Is there a better way of doing this?

I should note that I *want* the final image to have `_TILING_OPTIMAL`! And this is probably the most important design goal here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED` permits writing to the mapped memory (via `vkMapMemory`. It does not permit any other use, such as copy commands.

Comment: Okay thanks. I assume that's what they mean in vkspec when they write _"This layout is intended to be used as the initial layout for an image whose contents are written by the host"_, although I feel it could be more clearer by writing "host mapping" or something. But now at least I understand the error.

Comment: @alexpanter Theoreticaly host commands from the ` VK_EXT_host_image_copy` could handle the layout, but it is (surprisingly) optional.

Comment: that's interesting, though unfortunately not supported on my system. Also funnily enough they don't mention anything about `HOST_VISIBLE` or `DEVICE_LOCAL` memory types in https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCopyMemoryToImageEXT.html. In general the idea to avoid staging copies seems really nice, but maybe it could be possible to use transient memory for staging? Or would that be the same as `vkCopyMemoryToImageEXT`?
Btw. for now I just do an initial undefined->transfer_dst layout transition, which seems to be the canonical approach..